# How to scale vertical axis in increasing order from Bottom to Top in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

```
clear all;close all;clc
x =linspace(pi,2*pi,20)
y =linspace(0,pi,20)

C = [1 2];
imagesc(x,y,C)
colorbar
```

[image]

The vertical axis is not increasing from bottom to top.
May I know how to fix this? I have tried using `flipr()` so that vertical axis increase from bottom to top.

Comment: `imagesc` by default reverses the direction of the y-axis, to make it increasing again from bottom to top, use `set(gca,'YDir','normal')` after plotting.

Answer (score 1):

You are using an image, thus the axis are in `image` mode, where the coordinates start on the top left.

`imagesc` and other image showing functions automatically call `axis image;`. You can change that to the normal axis by calling `axis xy;` after the `imagesc` call.

Answer (score 1):

You can also change the direction of the y axis (or any axis) by changing the YDir property.

```
% Get the handle to the axes
ax = gca;

% Change the y axis direction
ax.YDir = 'normal';
```